# What is the correct CascadeType in @ManyToMany Hibernate annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, many-to-many, cascade

I am trying to model a transient operations solution schema in Hibernate and I am unsure how to get the object graph and behavior I want from the model.

The table structure uses a correlation table (many-to-many) to create lists of users for the operation:

```
Operation     OperationUsers      Users
op_id         op_id               user_id
...           user_id             ...
```

In modeling the persistent class Operation.java using hibernate annotations, I created:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="op_id")
public List<User> users() { return userlist; }
```

So far, I have the following questions:

1. When a user is removed from the list, how do I avoid Hibernate
   deleting the user from the Users table?  It should just be removed
   from the correlation table, not the Users table. I cannot see a valid
   CascadeType to accomplish this.
2. Do I need to put anything more in the method body?
3. Do I need to add more annotation arguments?
4. I am expecting to do this *without* futzing with the User class.
   Please tell me that I do not have to mess with User.java!

It's possible I'm overthinking this, but that's the nature of learning...  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the specific answer to my primary question (#1 and the main topic) is: "Do not specify any CascadeType on the property."

The answer is mentioned sorta sideways in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585836/hibernate-many-to-many-cascading-delete?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Hibernate defines and supports the following object states:
>
> *Transient - an object is transient if it has just been instantiated using the new operator, and it is not associated with a Hibernate Session. It has no persistent representation in the database and no identifier value has been assigned. Transient instances will be destroyed by the garbage collector if the application does not hold a reference anymore. Use the Hibernate Session to make an object persistent (and let Hibernate take care of the SQL statements that need to be executed for this transition).
>
> *Persistent - a persistent instance has a representation in the database and an identifier value. It might just have been saved or loaded, however, it is by definition in the scope of a Session. Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of work completes. Developers do not execute manual UPDATE statements, or DELETE statements when an object should be made transient.
>
> *Detached - a detached instance is an object that has been persistent, but its Session has been closed. The reference to the object is still valid, of course, and the detached instance might even be modified in this state. A detached instance can be reattached to a new Session at a later point in time, making it (and all the modifications) persistent again. This feature enables a programming model for long running units of work that require user think-time. We call them application transactions, i.e., a unit of work from the point of view of the user.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800814/is-it-possible-to-detach-hibernate-entity-so-that-changes-to-object-are-not-aut), you can detach your entity using Session.evict() to prevent hibernate from updating the database or simply clone it and make the needed changes on the copy.

Comment: When I say `operation.addUser(aUser)` I want Hibernate to execute `insert into correlation_table values (op_id, user_id)`, and when I say `operation.removeUser(aUser)` I want Hibernate to execute `delete from correlation_table where op_id = ? and user_id = ?`.  What I want to avoid is `delete from user where user_id = ?`.