# Spring JPA Many to Many: remove entity, remove entry in join table, BUT NOT REMOVE the other side

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this use case:

- I have Users.
- I have Groups.
- There is a N:N relation between Users and Groups.
- I can not delete Users.
- If I delete a Group, Users in that Group should not be deleted.

Users side:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
                    name = "USERS_GROUPS",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") ,
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") )
    private List<GroupJPA> groups;
```

Group side:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserJPA> returnsList;
```

If I delete a Group from User's group list, the group gets deleted from User's list, it gets deleted from the join table, and it doesn't get deleted from the Group table. This is the desire behavior.

But, if I delete an entire Group, what happens is, all the references in the join table get deleted, BUT ALSO the Users get deleted as well!! This can not happen.

I'm using 4.3.5.Final and Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE.

Comment: This appears to be a Hibernate/JPA question; I don't think that Spring is involved here.

Comment: Possibly might help you [cascading delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585836/hibernate-many-to-many-cascading-delete).

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the cascade = CascadeType.ALL from the

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<UserJPA> returnsList;
```

The cascading is propagating all operations to the relationship elements. Which means when you delete merge ,persist whatever...  These operations are also executed on the UserJPA entities.

Once you remove the group you need to be aware of who is the owner of the preationship. In your case the owner of the relationship is the UserJPA which means that all updates should happen through the owner.

Once the Cascading is removed you need to implement a method on the UserSide which looks like this:

```
removeFromGroup(Group group) {
    user.getGroups().remove(group);
    groups.removeUser(this);
}
```

This is in order to ensure that the collections are in sync.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have already tried removing CascadeType.ALL, and when I try to remove a Group, I get a constraint exception, because I'm deleting a Group, but I'm not deleting the regarding entry in the join table. But at least, removing the CascadeType.ALL, prevents the situation where I'm deleting an User., and the removing of a Group from a User's list still works fine.